# remove substring from first occurence of pattern 1 until nth occurence of pattern 2 perl

Tags: perl

`word,word2/word3,word4,word5`

how can i remove "/word3" ? including the slash but leave the comas?

I'm still very new to perl so I couldn't adapt the things I found.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do: what are those *pattern 1* and *pattern 2* you mention in the title? Give us more details please. It would be nice if you could show what you've tried to solve your problem (even if it doesn't work, surely you tried something)

Comment: You code a backslash but say a slash. Is it a backslash or a slash?

Comment: what i meant with first occurrence of first pattern 1 would be the "/" and the second occurrence of the second pattern would be ",". and yes I typed the "\" in the example but meant "/" sry

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$str =~ s/\\[^,]+//;
```

or if it is a forward slash:

```
$str =~ s~/[^,]+~~;
```

This will remove the (back)slash and every after that is not a comma.

Comment: `$str =~ s/\\[^,]//;` doesn't work, the substring is still there.

the real lines look like: `Filename,FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER_XXX,/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir3/dir4,ABC`

Comment: @Toto you probably forgot an `*` (or a `+`) : `s/\\[^,]*//`

Comment: @Zen: Then it's a forwardslash, not a backslash as in your example.Nevertheless, see my edit.

Comment: @Toto so it would be `$str =~ s/\/[^,]*//;` ? if i use it this way it remove everything after

Comment: @Zen: I've used a different delimiter (ie. `~`) to avoid escape the slash. But it's the same meaning.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression `s/pattern/replacement/`:

```
my $str = 'word,word2\word3,word4,word5';

$str =~ s/(\w+\,\w+)\\\w+(.+)/$1$2/;
```

This will produce: `word,word2,word4,word5`